# Hash code for expandable class (future proof)

Tags: java, math, hashcode, hash-function

Since I don't have any great skills in math, I ask you if there exists any algorithm that I should use for a class which probably will change in the future.

Consider following scenario:

Class "Roles" has following fields:

```
private boolean admin;
private boolean printer;
```

After some weeks I decide to add a role "guest":

```
private boolean admin;
private boolean printer;
private boolean guest;
```

After some weeks I decide to remove the role "printer";

```
private boolean admin;
private boolean guest;
```

Since I will persist the hashcode in a database, I must be 100% sure that all versions of this class generates unique hashcodes.

Maybe this is not a problem, I have always used the one provided in the Eclispe IDE source generator.

Can you please tell me if I am safe with the Eclipse IDE (Indigo) Java version >= 6 method or give me some other advices regarding this topic. I am sure this is a very common thing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like GUID/UUID or some other unique identifier generation fits your needs better than hashcodes.

Comment: GUIDs aren't generally guaranteed to be unique. There's a very low possibility of collision, but it's not zero.

Comment: But they are practically unique. After generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%. The odds are much higher that your data center will be hit by a meteorite. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: Your hash code is intended to describe the data format, like a [`serialVersionUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), right? Do you have any requirements regarding forward or backward compatibility? What do you use to persist stuff? As other comments noted, no hash will ever give you “100% sure” mathematically, but the odds of a collision can become extremely small. To be absolutely sure in theory, you'd have to maintain a list of assigned numbers and check to never use one a second time.

Comment: I only know one hashcode and its nature doesn't fit the one of this question. Changing hashcode for *UID would make the question less confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807139/store-hashcode-like-in-db-for-description-of-a-boolean-class-fields-to-increas to get a background of my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Since I will persist the hashcode in a database

Don't do that. The result of `hashCode` isn't *meant* to be persisted. In particular, from the docs:

> This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.

Next:

> I must be 100% sure that all versions of this class generates unique hashcodes.

Hash codes aren't meant to be unique, either... they very often *won't* be. Okay, you've only got 5 bits of data in your case, but in general that's not the case...

It sounds like you have different requirements from the normal ones for `Object.hashCode()` - so you shouldn't expect any autogenerated implementation to know about your special requirements. I suggest you state *exactly* what your requirements are, and we can work out what to do...

Comment: I believe that the “hash code” in question is only meant to describe the internal data layout. Probably we are not talking about `Object.hashCode()` here but rather about the `serialVersionUID` of [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), or something similar. Storing that as a format version id makes perfect sense.

Comment: @MvG: I suspect not, given that the OP talks about the "one provided in the Eclipse IDE source generator". If the OP *really* means serialVersionUID, I'd be surprised that he didn't mention it...

Comment: Thank you, can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807139/store-hashcode-like-in-db-for-description-of-a-boolean-class-fields-to-increas and I think you understand what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

To give some idea of the difference between 32 bit hashcodes and UUID's, and how likely a collision is per the [Birthday Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), this is how many ids you would need to generate to get a 50% chance that two of them have the same value (a collision):

32 bit hashcode - 77,000

128 bit UUID - 22,000,000,000,000,000,000

A hashcode does not promise uniqueness, with collisions to be expected in normal use. UUIDs promise practical uniqueness, where collisions are **extremely** unlikely in practice.

see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier