# Store "hashcode like" in db for description of a boolean class fields to increase performance and make named query short

Tags: java, math, jpa

The background to this question is the following:

[Hash code for expandable class (future proof)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801733/hash-code-for-expandable-class-future-proof)

However, I should mention why I would like to know this.

I have a class with many roles (boolean fields). I don't want to make named queries (JPA) like

```
@NamedQuery(name= "searchUserWithRoles", query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.role.admin = :admin AND u.role.printer = :printer AND ... .. . .+ 20 more booleans...)
```

My idea was to make a hashcode (or similar) for all fields in the Role class which reduce the named query to:

```
@NamedQuery(name= "searchUserWithRoles", query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.role.hashcode = :hashcode)
```

I think (but I am not sure) that this will increase the performance, but also make my queries very short (I have a more "Role" like fields in my user class).

Also, when I update the Role class with more roles fields I do not need to update the named queries.

So that is the background to the first question.

The new question is: Is there some way to generate a "hashcode like" field in the Role class that is a description of all fields that is true (even if the Role class is updated with more fields)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't need a "hash code" - you just need a bit mask. So long as you have 32 fields or fewer, you can store this in a 32-bit integer. If you have 64 fields or fewer, you can store this in a 64-bit integer.

Each field would then have one bit dedicated to it - so admin could be bit 0 (value 1), printer could be bit 1 (value 2), then next field would be bit 2 (value 4) etc. Just add together the values (effectively a bitwise OR).

Then to query for any particular combination, you'd just use a bitwise AND between the data and a "mask" with only the relevant bits set. So if you wanted to find every admin who didn't have printer rights, you'd check for `value & 3 == 1`.

Note that all of this may well interfere with any indexing the database would want to do, *and* the database may well optimize in this sort of way anyway. Do you have any evidence that storing them as separate fields - keeping your representation closer to your logical data structure - actually causes a problem?

Comment: Thanks Jon, I think your solution will perfectly fit my application. I will go for that =)